# Cannot create table SQLite Ionic 3

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I got an error when creating a table with SQLite with ionic 3. You can see the Error screenshot image. How to solve this?

```
createTable() {
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default'
    })
      .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', {})
          .then(() => alert('table created'))
          .catch(e => alert('table not created'));
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

[image]

Error detail tooltip:

> Argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter of type any[]. Property length is missing in type {}

[image]

Comment: what is the error message? You can see in problems tab or hover...

Comment: Argument of type {} is not assignable to parameter of type any[]. Property length is missing in type {}

Answer (score 0):

According to the [@ionic-native/sqlite](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/src/%40ionic-native/plugins/sqlite/index.ts) code:

```
@CordovaInstance()
  executeSql(statement: string, params?: any[]): Promise<any> {
    return;
  }
```

The second parameter is of type array not object. Try:

```
db.executeSql('create table danceMoves(name VARCHAR(32))', [])
      .then(() => alert('table created'))
      .catch(e => alert('table not created'));
```

**Update**:
Submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/2805) to fix in the documentation.

Comment: Interestingly, OP's code is copied straight from [the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/). I'm guessing at some point it took objects but that was changed and the docs not updated.

Comment: @Shawn ah.. Guess they missed it

Comment: (Or it could have just been a typo from the start and whoever wrote that never bothered to test it)